# Convert promise function to async/await

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await

I am trying to convert this function to async/await. But got confused. Is there a way to do it?

```
const csv = require('fast-csv');
const inputFileFolder = 'upload';

    const readData = (inputFileName) => {
      const csvData = [];

      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        csv
          .fromPath(`${inputFileFolder}/${inputFileName}`)
          .on('data', (data) => {
            csvData.push(data);
          })
          .on('end', () => {
            resolve(csvData);
          })
          .on('error', () => {
            reject(new Error('Something went wrong while reading the CSV file.'));
          });
      });
    };
```

Comment: what's the question?

Comment: You can't use `async/await` with that - you need to use it within the function that is handling the promise.

Comment: I guess you could `await new Promise` instead of `return new Promise` but that doesn't really accomplish anything useful - per @Jack, if you want to use `await` with it, use `await` in the *consumer* of `readData`

Comment: @JackBashford I do it. But was wondering if I can make this async/await.

Comment: Why? "making it async/await" you'll still need to "promisify" `csv.fromPath` - async await is not used to make callback style code into Promise style code - is is, as has already been said twice, used for the consumer of Promises

Answer (score 1):

`async..await` provides syntactic sugar for `then` and `catch` promise methods to chain promises in synchronous-like manner.

Since the promise is created but not chained, the use of `async..await` won't improve the code. `new Promise` is still needed with `async..await` when there's no promise to chain.

Answer (score -1):

You can only use `await` if you declare it in a `async` function. 
You can use it and then use correct error handling. 
But if you want to use `await` you could use

```
async function name() {
  await // Your code here
};
```

Comment: I know how to write async function. My problem was converting this particular one.

Comment: return new Promise(async function(resolve, reject) {};